# ng-repeat won't work when sending form funciton

Tags: angularjs

Here is my controller :

```
.controller('RouteController', function($scope,$timeout, $stateParams, Account) {

    $scope.showRouteByCity= function(cityName){
      Account.getRouteByCity(cityName).then(function (response) {
        $scope.routesByCities = response.data.routeSatart;
        console.log($scope.routesByCities);
      });
    }
}
```

Here I send array of objects. When i check console, i can see this :
[image]

And when i try to use `ng-repeat` for this object i only get blank screen.

Here is my code from view

```
<ion-view view-title="All routes">
  <ion-content>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat=" tt in routesByCities">{{tt.time}}</li>
    </ul>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Is there some special method to send variable to view? If I use fucntion or I made some error that i can't see.

Here is what i get in response :
[Account.getRouteByCity(cityName) - reponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r143.png)

SOLUTION 1.

For some reasone, when I use function, it don't want to show me info on view. I found this solution and it works. It's not so clean and nice, so if someone else have any other solution, please, share it.

```
var cityName = $stateParams.city;
    Account.getRouteByCity(cityName).then(function (response) {
      $scope.routesByCities = response.data.routeSatart;
      console.log($scope.routesByCities);
    });
```

Here I use StateParams to get city name form Url and then i show routes.I don't understand why it don't work with function()...

Comment: Does `getRouteByCity()` return an angularjs promise (`$q.defer().promise`)?

Comment: Is it a typo here ``response.data.routeSatart;`` should this be ``response.data.routeStart;``

Comment: It's not a type, that is ok. I get all my objects on console. 
and here is my getRouteByCity() 
`getRouteByCity: function(cityName) {
        return $http.get('url'+cityName);
      }`

Comment: Can you post the output of ``respnose`` from the Account.getRouteByCity(cityName) call.

Comment: And when you inspect the element, does a list of `<li>` gets populated? Because perhaps you're just not pointing to the correct attribute (`time`)? You can try replace the expression with `{{ tt | json }}` to see what's inside `tt`

Comment: Is it the only thing you get in the console? Is the function called only once? How is it called?

Comment: I update my answer with one more image. You can see what i get in response. I run function with `ng-click="showRouteByCity(city.city)"`
There i get city name and all routes for that city. But for some resons i can't see that info. on my view.. :/ And all objects have the same properties.

Comment: Also in my controller i have this one :
` Account.getCity().then(function (response) {
          $scope.cities = response.data.cities;
          console.log($scope.cities);

        });`
Here I get all cities, and this works ok with ng- repeat. First i have list of cities, then when user click on city, i show him some routes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<ion-view view-title="All routes">
  <ion-content>
    <ul ng-repeat=" item in routesByCities">
      <li>{{item.time}}</li>
    </ul>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

OR

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-item collection-repeat="item in routesByCities">
    {{item.time}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```